# Verb+Noun Combination // なる to "describe landscapes"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I stumbled upon following sentence:

> 至る所に水路が**張り巡らされ青**が際立つ街並みになっている。

I wanted to ask which grammatical construction lies behind 「張り巡らされ青」. The context it appears in is the description of a (fictional) Onsen-town.

Further I am unsure how to interpret 「なっている」. I can image that (judging from it being the description of an Onsen-town) meaning something like "the scenery changed into...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've parsed this incorrectly. Think:

至る所に水路が張り巡らされ(て)、青が際立つ街並みになっている。

Waterways were peppered throughout, with the townscape featuring heavily the color blue.

・When connecting two phrases together with "て", you don't actually need the "て". This makes the sentence sound more formal/academic.

・As for the なっている at the end, it carries a similar meaning to  "です". You could perhaps think "has become" → "is". It however does not necessarily imply that there was a time when what is before になっている wasn't the case.

Comment: Thank you very much it is pretty clear to me now. Do you know the grammatical operation behind the missing "て" or is it just something regarding formality?

Comment: 連用形 was originally used without "て" to string together verbs. In speech we tend to use "て", but we don't necessarily have to (it comes from the addition and conjugation of [「つ」という助動詞](https://kotobank.jp/word/つ-570135#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) to the 連用形 of a verb). It most likely remained in 文語 because, like many older forms of words (like である), it sounds more academic and proper than the spoken version.

Comment: Thank you, especially for linking a detailed description !